# How search only in records that have value (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have this part of code:

```
int[] toRemoveInChildHotelOffersMealsIds = _hotelOfferDetailsRepository.Get()
                .Where(x => toRemoveHotelOfferMealsIds.Contains(x.ParentId.Value))
                .Select(x => x.ID)
                .ToArray();
```

This code must return child ids to remove if exist.

And this section throws an error

> Nullable object must have a value

in unit tests. And second thing I don't understand why I don't get the same exception during real work.

So how can I modify my code to avoid this exception and search only in records that have a value?

Comment: In your Unit tests you have hotel offers without parent. Handle that this can be null by using nullable.HasValue

Comment: You mean something like that ? 
int[] toRemoveInChildHotelOffersMealsIds = _hotelOfferDetailsRepository.Get()
     .Where(x => x.ParentId.HasValue ? toRemoveHotelOfferMealsIds.Contains(x.ParentId.Value) : false)
     .Select(x => x.ID)
     .ToArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because the value of *ParentId* is resolved to null and *ParentId.Value* throws and exception. Are you setting a value for *ParentId* where the data is mocked?

To avoid this, do a null check (assuming the ones that doesn't have a ParentId value must be ignored)

```
int[] toRemoveInChildHotelOffersMealsIds = _hotelOfferDetailsRepository.Get()
                    .Where(x => x.ParentId.HasValue ? toRemoveHotelOfferMealsIds.Contains(x.ParentId.Value) : false)
                    .Select(x => x.ID)
                    .ToArray();
```

If they need to be considered, then use

```
int[] toRemoveInChildHotelOffersMealsIds = _hotelOfferDetailsRepository.Get()
                    .Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue || toRemoveHotelOfferMealsIds.Contains(x.ParentId.Value))
                    .Select(x => x.ID)
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes, there are records without parent id, and i want to know how search only in records which have.

Comment: @игорьмаркив : Have you tried the above query I gave in the answer?

Comment: Why u use revert bool? its not seems to be rigth on my opinion

i thing code need be like this than : 

    int[] toRemoveInChildHotelOffersMealsIds = _hotelOfferDetailsRepository.Get()
     .Where(x => x.ParentId.HasValue ? toRemoveHotelOfferMealsIds.Contains(x.ParentId.Value) : false)
     .Select(x => x.ID)
     .ToArray();

If HAS value THAN do thing OR false (pass) ?

Comment: @игорьмаркив If the ParentId is null, the first condition become true and the 2nd condition will be bypassed. If there is ParentId, 2nd condition will be checked. If possible, try it and let me know if its working.

Comment: @игорьмаркив Apologies. I understood the scenario differently. The code was just targeted to resolve the exception. Modifying the answer